# How to play 'http:/....... /mp3' with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I can't play mp3 audio file.

```
URL_PATH = @"http://...../.…./A1.mp3";
```

NSError *error;

```
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL_PATH] error:&error];
if (error) 
{
    NSLog(@"error:%@",error.localizedDescription);
}

if (player ==nil)
{
    NSLog(@"nil");
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"playing");
    [player play];
}
```

error code :

```
error:The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)
nil
```

How can I do?
Please tell me hint. pre-Thanks!

Comment: I'll tag this with obj-c.  You'll have better luck.

Comment: this happens in the simulator or in the device ?

Answer (score 7):

You are using the wrong player to play audio captured from a network stream. See Apple's documentation on `AVAudioPlayer`:

> Apple recommends that you use this class for audio playback **unless** you
>   are playing audio captured from a network stream or require very low
>   I/O latency. For an overview of audio technologies, see Audio & Video
>   Starting Point and “Using Audio” in Multimedia Programming Guide.

One work around way to use `AVAudioPlayer` is to fetch the audio's data and put it in a `NSData`. Then you can init your `AVAudioPlayer` by `initWithData:error:`. Also, don't put the code in your main queue. Else it will block your user interface from reacting to user's input.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSURL *mp3URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://zhangmenshiting.baidu.com/data2/music/44799433/4479927746800128.mp3?xcode=dbff90a141d5d136fdc7275fdc3fae126077a44adc974ad8"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:mp3URL];
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:NULL];
    [self.audioPlayer play];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

sunkehappy is right, AVAudioPlayer isn't meant for streaming audio. It is meant for playing audio files and for data that is already in memory. That's why you need to init it with the data and not with the URL.

Here's the apple answer (which you can find here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1634/_index.html ):

> The AVAudioPlayer class does not provide support for streaming audio
>   based on HTTP URL's. The URL used with initWithContentsOfURL: must be
>   a File URL (file://). That is, a local path.

If you look for an audio streamer, you can test that [audio streamer](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer).